# Preferences dynamically created are deleted on restart if at default

Tags: firefox-addon

I create a new branch and pref on that branch like this:

```
var _branchLive = Services.prefs.getBranch('extensions.rawr@jetpack.');
var _branchDefault = Services.prefs.getDefaultBranch('extensions.rawr@jetpack.');
_branchDefault.setBoolPref('mypref', true);
_branchLive.setBoolPref('mypref', true);
```

However after restarting the browser the pref is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the default branch incorrectly.

```
var _branchDefault = Services.prefs.getDefaultBranch(null);
_branchDefault.setBoolPref('extensions.rawr@jetpack.mypref', true);
```

**Update:**
The normal procedure is that the add-on sets the default pref, on every startup (via `/defaults/preferences/pref.js` in overlay add-ons or manually in case of bootstrapped add-ons).

Firefox uses these default values unless the value is changed, then Firefox saves the changed value in `about:config`

So on shut down, only the values that are changed (by user via add-on's Options or by the add-on itself) will be saved.

In your case, the default value and the set value are the same, so nothing is changed.

Try this and see:

```
// set the default value
var _branchDefault = Services.prefs.getDefaultBranch(null);
_branchDefault.setBoolPref('extensions.rawr@jetpack.mypref', true);

// change the value via addon
var _branchLive = Services.prefs.getBranch('extensions.rawr@jetpack.');
_branchLive.setBoolPref('mypref', false);
```

Also look here: [How to convert an overlay extension to restartless](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/How_to_convert_an_overlay_extension_to_restartless#Step_4.3A_Manually_handle_default_preferences)

Comment: True it persists if it's not at the default value. But im trying to get the default value to persist, maybe i should write to `/defaults/preferences/pref.js`?

Comment: To get a default value to persist, you can try setting it to a temp value that is NOT desired and then change it to a value that is desired ... but what is the point anyway? You have to set it on each restart. Once the code is written to the addon, the addon code is not going to change the next time it is restarted!

Comment: Yeah theres no point ot setting it to undesired values I was hoping to make the default value persist even if at default. lol

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do. Do you want a default that remains after the addon is uninstalled? That would against AMO rules. Do you want a default that remain after each restart? That is pointless. Since the code to set the default is inside the addon, it will run with every restart and will be set with every restart. You gain nothing by setting a persistent default. Even in an overlay addon, the default is re-read and re-set with every restart. Firefox does not save the default prefs. If you want a persistent pref, then it has to be set as normal pref (not default).

Comment: Thanks so much man for this discussion. If removing default prefs on uninstall is required, why doesnt AMO require removing user set prefs? On uninstall of addons I remove all my prefs, regardless of default or user set. I just want default prefs persisting between browser shutdown to startups, until unintsalled, i want them to behave same way as user_set values. I learned that in a chat earlier, so i think ill just have to set default everytime :(

Comment: Default prefs are not relevant in removal on uninstall since they will not be saved anyway ;) There is no other option but to set it every time. That is the normal process. You can set a first run pref and then not run alter but the code will still reside in addon so the extra effort and coding is not beneficial anyway. let me explain: addon has some code to set the default pref once. On restart the addon code does not change so the same process will be repeated anyway. so why bother will extra coding?

Comment: Dan so you were right, prefs that are at default value do not persist across browse closes and startups. So silly. Ill just have to create it everytime :(

Comment: @Noitidart .. the purpose of default prefs is 1) to have a starting point 2) to have a reset value .. that is all. For prefs that need to be persistent, there is the user pref (whether set by the addon user or the addon itself) :)